# How can I easily set up a MERN stack with existing code?

Tags: npm, package.json, mern, npm-start

I am attempting to complete a website for my senior project and wish to develop a MERN stack on Ubuntu as I was told to "pick something I have never worked with before that will help in the job field". With this being said I have created my front end code using HTML and CSS files. I have also set up an Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine and installed Node, React, npm, and MongoDB. but have ran into difficulties when i try to run npm start I get the following error:

```
> realestate@1.0.0 start
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

/home/kayla/realestate/node_modules/concurrently/dist/src/command.js:78
                exitCode: exitCode ?? String(signal),
                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mckayla/realafacts/node_modules/concurrently/dist/src/index.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

My package.son file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "realestate",
  "version": "1.0.0", 
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried to troubleshoot this issue but cannot figure out said problem. Please let me know of any changes to the package.json file that would help improve it as well if needed. I can also provide additional information if needed.